# asio::io_context run in thread, asio::steady_timer::async_wait doesn't work

Tags: c++, networking, asio

I have tried to create a server with asio, when i try to integrate a timer behind the event handler from client.

```
        asio::io_context m_asioContext;
        std::thread m_threadContext;
        void print()
        {
            std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
            SendTimer();
        }

        void SendTimer()
        {
            asio::steady_timer timer(m_asioContext, asio::chrono::seconds(2));
            timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&server_interface::print, this));
        }           

        bool Start()
        {
            try
            {
                // Issue a task to the asio context - This is important
                // as it will prime the context with "work", and stop it
                // from exiting immediately. Since this is a server, we 
                // want it primed ready to handle clients trying to
                // connect.
                WaitForClientConnection();

                std::cout << "[SERVER] Started!azazaz\n";
                // Launch the asio context in its own thread
                m_threadContext = std::thread([this]() { m_asioContext.run(); });
            }
            catch (std::exception& e)
            {
                // Something prohibited the server from listening
                std::cerr << "[SERVER] Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
                return false;
            }

            std::cout << "[SERVER] Started!\n";
            return true;
        }

        void Update(size_t nMaxMessages = -1, bool bWait = false)
        {
            if (bWait) m_qMessagesIn.wait();

            // Process as many messages as you can up to the value
            // specified

            size_t nMessageCount = 0;
            while (nMessageCount < nMaxMessages && !m_qMessagesIn.empty())
            {
                // Grab the front message
                auto msg = m_qMessagesIn.pop_front();

                // Pass to message handler
                OnMessage(msg.remote, msg.msg);

                nMessageCount++;
            }

            Update(nMaxMessages, bWait);
        }
```

Server call

```
CustomServer server(60000);
server.Start();
asio::io_context io;
server.Update(-1, true);
```

It'seem that the timer could not run correctly. Just like the infinitive loop. I really newbie with asio. So I wonder how we could keep multi event with only a thread.

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function SendTimer() immediately returns and the timer gets destroyed. Make a shared pointer to the timer and send the shared pointer to the callback, or make the timer a permanent member of the server_interface class. Here's the first solution:

```
auto timer = std::make_shared<asio::steady_timer>(m_asioContext, std::chrono::seconds(2));
timer->async_wait(m_asioContext, [timer /* ,this, &server_interface, or whatever else you need */]
    (std::error_code ec)
    {
        if(!ec) 
        {
            print();
        }
         else { /* handle error here */ }
    }
);
```